# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar un poco la apariencia del HTML?

Tags: html, html5

**Hola Comunidad!**

Estoy aprendiendo HTML5 pero me gustaría cambiar un poco la apariencia simple que tiene. He investigado en internet y he visto que hay que usar un lenguaje llamado CSS pero no sé como se usa y como implementarlo en el archivo HTML. Si me pudieseís echar un cable estaría muy agradecido. Os dejo un pequeño ejemplo de código HTML por si me podéis ayudar en algo. Me gustaría poner si puede ser el color negro en la página, tipo dark mode y las letras de algún color que se vea o si puede ser algún tipo de letra llamativo. Igualmente me encuentro con el problema de que los párrafos que escribo con la etiqueta `<p>` no tiene un doble espaciado como me gustaría. Gracias por la ayuda

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Web de Juan Carlos</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Este es el sitio web de Juan Carlos</h1>
        <p>Hola a tod@s. Mi nombre es Juan Carlos y este va a ser mi sitio web personal</p>
        <p>Actualmente me encuentro aprendiendo HTML5</p>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Tu pregunta es muy amplia, [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/First_steps/Getting_started) es un lenguaje con demasiado contenido, te recomiendo ir aprendiendolo, revisa este enlace y conforme avances podrás ir agregando los estilos deseados

Comment: De igual modo, al igual que @BetaM te recomiendo que, vayas aprendiéndolo poco a poco, ya que tiene bastante contenido y personalmente, creo que es bastante útil. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por las sugerencias. Usaré el enlace proporcionado para poder aprender sobre este lenguaje y poder personalizar un poco más los archivos HTML. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder añadir estilos a un archivo HTML es necesario hacer uso de CSS.

CSS o Hoja de estilos en cascada hace uso de **propiedades** para modificar los estilos del HTML. Lo que buscas son estilos muy simples. Las propiedades que permiten esta modificación son bastante autodescriptibles. Existen bastantes propiedades que permiten modificar por completo el HTML.

A continuación, para tu propósito vamos hacer uso de las siguientes propiedades:

```
font-family = Tipo de letra (Fuente)
color = Color del texto
background – color = Color de fondo
```

Las propiedades de CSS se construyen referenciando a la etiqueta HTML que queramos aplicar el estilo. Por ejemplo, si queremos modificar el contenido de la etiqueta `<p>` se modifica de la siguiente forma:

```
p {
    propiedad1: parámetro;
    propiedad2: parámetro;
}
```

En tu código puedes implementar CSS de dos formas:

1. Implementar el estilo en el propio archivo HTML haciendo uso de la etiqueta `<style>`
2. Implementar los estilos en un archivo con extensión `.css` aparte e incrustarlo en el archivo con extensión `.html`

Uso de la etiqueta `<style>` en el archivo `.html`:

Haciendo uso de la etiqueta `<style>` en el **head** del archivo HTML podemos implementar los estilos necesarios para nuestro archivo. En tu caso, sería de la siguiente forma:

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Web de Juan Carlos</title>
    <style>
      body {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        font-family: Helvetica;
      }

      h1 {
        color: red;
        font-family: Algerian;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Este es el sitio web de Juan Carlos</h1>
    <p>Hola a tod@s. Mi nombre es Juan Carlos y este va a ser mi sitio web personal</p>
    <p><br>Actualmente me encuentro aprendiendo HTML5</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Implementar los estilos en un archivo con extensión `.css` aparte e incrustarlo en el archivo con extensión `.html`

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Web de Juan Carlos</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Este es el sitio web de Juan Carlos</h1>
    <p>Hola a tod@s. Mi nombre es Juan Carlos y este va a ser mi sitio web personal</p>
    <p><br>Actualmente me encuentro aprendiendo HTML5</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-family: Helvetica;
}
  
h1 {
    color: red;
    font-family: Algerian;
}
```

Para implementar el archivo con extensión `.css` en el código HTML hacemos uso de la etiqueta `<link>` la cual **NO** tiene **etiqueta de cierre**. Esta etiqueta tiene la forma:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
```

Donde `rel` es un atributo de HTML que describe la relación que mantiene el documento de destino con el documento presente (el que enlaza). Por otro lado, `type` es una versión específica del elemento `<input>`, que se usa para representar a un campo de entrada de texto. Por último, con el atributo `href` indica la URL de un archivo. Es importante que se especifique el nombre concreto del archivo CSS a implementar, de lo contrario, el archivo referenciado será otro y los estilos pueden verse alterados.

**Código completo reproducible:**

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-family: Helvetica;
}
  
h1 {
    color: green;
    font-family: Algerian;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Web de Juan Carlos</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Este es el sitio web de Juan Carlos</h1>
    <p>Hola a tod@s. Mi nombre es Juan Carlos y este va a ser mi sitio web personal</p>
    <p><br>Actualmente me encuentro aprendiendo HTML5</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Si deseas que tú parráfo `<p>` incluya un doble espaciado, equivalente a un `enter` puedes hacer uso de la etiqueta `<br>` en el párrafo que quieras que se aprecie dicho cambio. Esta etiqueta **NO** tiene **etiqueta de cierre.**

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda. Tengo una duda, ¿Si hago: p { color: pink } se cambiaría el color del párrafo?

Comment: En efecto, con esa instrucción puedes cambiar el color del párrafo a rosa. Saludos